# RxJava 2 requires different Observable return type than RxJava 1 (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am updating my project from RxJava 1 to RxJava 2. I have this extension method (I use Kotlin):

```
fun <T : DatabaseModel> Observable<DataSnapshot?>.toObjectObservable(type: Class<T>): Observable<T> {
    return this.map {
        if (it == null) {
            return@map null
        }
        val data = it.getValue(type)
        data?.setId(it.key)
        data
    }
}
```

When I used RxJava 1 everything was OK. But as I replaced the observables with new Observables from RxJava 2 (io.reactivex.Observable) error occured. Now the IDE says that it needs following return type:

```
((Datasnashot) -> T)!
```

instead of provided

```
(Datasnapshot) -> T?
```

Do you have any idea what may cause this different behavior? How should I change the code to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RxJava 2 `Observable` no longer accepts `null` in any way. Your `map` lambda is producing a `T?` but it needs to be a `T`. You can assume the input is non-null, and if you also assume `DataSnapshot.getValue()` is non-null, your code shortens to

```
fun <T : DatabaseModel> Observable<DataSnapshot>.toObjectObservable(type: Class<T>): Observable<T> {
    return this.map {
        val data = it.getValue(type)!!
        data.setId(it.key)
        data
    }
}
```

Of course, this will NPE (wrapped into an `Observable.error()`) if `DataSnapshot.getValue()` returns null. If you want, you could handle that specially, for example by dropping them.

```
fun <T : DatabaseModel> Observable<DataSnapshot>.toObjectObservable(type: Class<T>): Observable<T> {
    return this.flatMap {
        val data = it.getValue(type)
        data.?setId(it.key)
        if (data != null) Observable.just(data) else Observable.empty()
    }
}
```